# How to change values of fields of a class(object) in form class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, object

I design a time class

```
` class Time_Class
    {
        private int minute;
        private int second;
        private int hour;

        //Default constructor
        public Time_Class()
        {
            this.minute = 0;
            this.second = 0;
            this.hour = 0;
        }

        //Constructor overload
        public Time_Class(int mm, int ss, int hh)
        {
            this.minute = mm;
            this.second = ss;
            this.hour = hh;
        }

        //Method for setting time
        public void Set_Time(int mm,int ss,int hh)
        {
            this.minute = mm;
            this.second = ss;
            this.hour = hh;      
        }

        //Method of Getting 24 Hour time
        public string[] Get24Time()
        {
            int[] time = new int[3];
            time[0] = this.minute;
            time[1] = this.second;
            time[2] = this.hour;

            if (time[1] > 59)
            {
                time[1] = 0;
                time[0] += 1;         
            }
            if (time[0] > 59)
            {
                time[0] = 0;
                time[2] += 1;
            }
            if (time[2] > 24)
            {
                time[0] = 0;
                time[1] = 0;
                time[2] = 0;
            }

            string[] ret = new string[3];
            ret[0] = time[0].ToString();
            ret[1] = time[1].ToString();
            ret[2] = time[2].ToString();

            return ret;         
        }

        //Method of Getting 12 Houur time
        public string[] Get12Time()
        {
            string ampm = "AM";
            int[] time = new int[2];
            time[0] = this.minute;
            time[1] = this.second;
            time[2] = this.hour;

            if (time[1] > 59)
            {
                time[1] = 0;
                time[0] += 1;
            }
            if (time[0] > 59)
            {
                time[0] = 0;
                time[2] += 1;
            }
            if (time[2] > 12)
            {
                time[0] = 0;
                time[1] = 0;
                time[2] = 0;
                if (ampm == "PM")
                {
                    ampm = "AM";
                    goto b;
                }
                if (ampm=="AM")
                {
                    ampm = "PM";
                }

            }
        b:
            string[] ret = new string[3];
            ret[0] = time[0].ToString();
            ret[1] = time[1].ToString();
            ret[2] = time[2].ToString();
            ret[3] = ampm;

            return ret;         
        }
```

`

I want to to create an object of this class in winform (Form class) and want to change values of class(object) fields on timer tick event.

I do like this.

```
 Time_Class t1 = new Time_Class();

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //code
        }
```

But in timer tick, object of this class is not calling, which i define out side of timer tick.

How i call an object of this class in timer tick and change the values of fields of that class(object).

Comment: Please look up the `else` and `else if` control flow statements and remove that `goto`

Comment: Yes it is Windows form timer and its enabled property is false but I start timer on Load foam event like 'timer1.Start();'

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, i'll do it but it does not matter on requirement.

Comment: Which is why that, and the following, are comments. Also check out the `Timespan` class as well. You can also remove the assignments in your default constructor and leave it empty since those will all default to zero anyways.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 OK.. I got it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to make fields public:

```
 public int minute {get;set;}
 public int second {get;set;}
 public int hour {get;set;}
```

Comment: Yes . now object is calling on timer tick.